# MariaDB failed to start on Debian After Upgrading Server

Tags: debian, mariadb, magento

I am running magento application on debian server. MariaDB failed to start after server upgrade. Please find the errors below:

I am running magento on Debian Linux server. The site failed to load with error 521.

MariaDB is not running.
I tried to start the service, but it is returning an error.

```
Max address space         unlimited            unlimited            bytes
Max file locks            unlimited            unlimited            locks
Max pending signals       31852                31852                signals
Max msgqueue size         819200               819200               bytes
Max nice priority         0                    0
Max realtime priority     0                    0
Max realtime timeout      unlimited            unlimited            us
Core pattern: core
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 2G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority()
.
2022-01-11  7:44:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=7898622907
2022-01-11 07:44:23 0x7f66204fcf40  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /bitnami/blacksmith-sandox/mariadb-10.3.31/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 3912
InnoDB: Failing assertion: rec_offset <= srv_page_size
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
220111  7:44:23 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
To report this bug, see https://mariadb.com/kb/en/reporting-bugs
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

MariaDB KnowledgeBaseMariaDB KnowledgeBase
InnoDB Recovery Modes
Modes for recovering from emergency situations in InnoDB.

MariaDB KnowledgeBaseMariaDB KnowledgeBase
MariaDB Community Bug Reporting
Guidelines for reporting bugs in MariaDB software.
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Fastest solution: Purge and reinstall MariaDB and restore the backup you made before you started the upgrade.

Comment: Hi
There is no backup. MariaDB stopped working due to low disk space. So, I upgraded the server and performed reboot.
So How can I correct this issue?

Comment: Now that was a great idea with a broken database. Your error message tells you what to do: `Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/ about forcing recovery`